# Android - Disable screen support x large screens

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to disable support for extra large screens in the android manifest file?  We have developed an app, but have yet to alter the design for tablets, so we would like to disable tablet support until a later release.

We have developed the app using phonegap/html5 - so our Java knowledge is limited.

My manifest file lists the following -

```
 <supports-screens
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:resizeable="true"
 android:anyDensity="true"
 />
```

is there a property for extra large screens?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Your manifest file is missing :)

Comment: sorry!  Formatting error - just added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paul, have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

The code to disable extra large screens is

```
<supports-screens
 android:xlargeScreens="false"
 />
```

From what I'm seeing, this still allows you to run the app on a tablet device from Eclipse but should disable it at publish time.

Comment: HI carignan.boy, In my application I have defined android:minSdkVersion="4" in the manifest file. I posted my problem in stackoverflow but didn't yet get any proper answer. If you could help me, really gratefull. The link is as follows. [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650234/android-mess-up-the-ui-controls-in-large-screen-size?answertab=active#tab-top ].... Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) element in the Manifest, it lets you customize, what kind of screens does your application support. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article about Supporting [Multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) or you can read about optimizing your [app for tablet](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html) or you can [let your app to strech](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-mode-for-apps-on-large-screens.html) (just like iPhone app runs on iPad).

I think 3rd article would be more appropriate at this stage. Good luck.